# nil returned when accessing ruby/rails instance variable's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error- (nil when i log debug the value) when I try to access the instance variables id as @line_item.id below. but [:id] works fine
Why is that?

```
@cart = current_cart
@line_item = @cart.line_items.find_by_id(params[:id])
@line_item =  @line_item.decrement_quantity(@line_item[:id])
```

Comment: You sure you want the same instance variable being assigned on both lines? Can you check the class of @line_item (puts @line_item.class)

Comment: logger output for that is "line item class is LineItem" ;I dont have to use the same instance but I dont hink it matters much here

Comment: @line_item.id and @line_item[:id] should return the same value when you are dealing with an object. Check it in your rails console

Comment: one more, as you are calling instance method on `@line_item` object you dont need `@line_item.id` as parameter to the method. you can access `self.id` inside method directly

Answer (score 0):

As @Kyle said, @line_item.id and @line_item[:id] should return the same value.

one more, as you are calling instance method on `@line_item` object you dont need 
`@line_item.id` as parameter to the method. you can access `self.id` inside method directly

I would suggest writing something like -

```
@cart = current_cart
@line_item = @cart.line_items.find_by_id(params[:id])
@line_item.decrement_quantity


## inside model 
class LineItem < 
  def decrement_quantity
    puts self.id # will print the id of object calling method
  end
end
```